# Extract alphabets, space and comma from string in android

Tags: java, android, extract, replaceall

I have a string mixed with numbers and alphabets as below, with that i am doing following replacement

```
String fullString = "08094 Williamstown, New Jersey";  
String extractedString = fullString .replaceAll("[^a-z^A-Z]", "");
```

the result i am getting is : WilliamstownNewJersey
but i want it like : Williamstown, New Jersey

How can i get it ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex checks for non-alphabets this includes comma and spaces.

For this case you can try

```
String extractedString = fullString .replaceAll("\\d", "").trim();
```

or

```
String extractedString = fullString .replaceAll("[0-9]", "").trim();
```

You can check your regex online here.

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: best answer but you may want to also add `.trim()` after the `replaceAll()` since you will get a leading space that may not be wanted.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex, hope will suffice your need.

```
([^a-zA-Z, ])
```